# In a WPF datagrid, how do I get the new row after cell edit?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

My `DataGrid` is bound to a `DataTable`. After each cell edit in the grid, I need to get the new `DataRow` value. I get the new values only after the focus is lost from the row and not the cell.

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding}" CellEditEnding="grid_CellEditEnding"/>


private void grid_CellEditEnding(object sender, DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs e)
{  
   //Both the DataTable and the row obtained from "e" has the old row. 
}
```

What should I do to get the new `DataRow`?

Comment: This is normal, in CellEditEnding you have only information about row you are editing

Comment: @demonplus I do want the row that is edited. In that method I have used,  I get only the old row values where as I want the new row values.

Comment: and what would you do with new row information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As its name hints, the `CellEditEnding` event gets fired right before the edit is commited. Sadly, since there is no CellEditEnded event, there's no straightforward way to do what you want.

You have three options here:

1. Set the cell's Bindings `UpdateSourceTrigger` to `PropertyChanged`, so the changes are applied on the fly instead of waiting for the commit.
2. Set the cell's Bindings `NotifyOnSourceUpdated` to `True` and then add `Binding.AddSourceUpdatedHandler(MyDataGrid,OnDataGridSourceUpdated)` in code-behind (look here for more info: http://wpf.codeplex.com/discussions/39356).
3. Or handle both the `CellEditEnding` and `RowEditEnding` events. In the CellEditEnding, use `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` to force a `DataGrid.CommitEdit()` call. And in the RowEditEnding, use `BeginInvoke` again to execute your code. It'll execute after the row edit has been commited, but you'll have to manually retrieve the row value by its index or something like that (check a similar example here (point 5): http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vinsibal/archive/2009/04/14/5-more-random-gotchas-with-the-wpf-datagrid.aspx) - Keep in mind that since you don't have control over when your code is executed, your items could have changed further, be rearranged or something like that, so this isn't 100% reliable without some work from your part.

Comment: I don't have a cell binding. I have bound the entire grid to a DataTable. I tried using BeginInvoke but to no avail. The BeginInvoke works only if I use RowEditEnding. But I need the new row on CellEditEnding.

Comment: The problem is that there is no new row on CellEditEnding, since the changes haven't been commited yet. No change has been applied to your DataRow object. You could force them to be applied by calling the `DataGrid.CommitEdit()` method. That should fire the RowEditEnding event every time you edit a cell, and you can then use the `BeginInvoke` approach from the RowEditEnding handler.

Comment: Updated my 3rd point to reflect this suggestion... A bit too convoluted, but should work...

Comment: I used a Dispatcher.BeginInvoke in CellEditEnding to call a dummy method. That did not invoke RowEditEnding event. I'm guessing this is what you asked me to do?

Comment: Call `DataGrid.CommitEdit` on that method. That should fire the RowEditEnding event.

Answer (score 0):

While the DataTable still contains the old value, the Control (aka Textbox) has the new value.
so

```
Private Sub dataGrid_CellEditEnding(sender As Object, e As 
    DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs) Handles dataGrid.CellEditEnding
        Dim strNewValue As String = CType(e.EditingElement, TextBox).Text
    End Sub
```

Will get you the new Value. Note that this only works for TextColumns, you would have to check the type of the EditingElement if you have other types.

And